# SPSS/PSPP Insert command does not work anymore

Tags: insert, spss, pspp

I'm using the INSERT command to read the Syntax files. It worked perfectly till now, however when I want to insert the newest syntax (like I usually did) the error is that an active dataset has to be set or that some variable names don't exist (even if they do). When I run the Syntax that I want to insert, there is no error occurring.
Did someone encounter this problem as well, or does someone know a solution to this?

This is the code and error:

```
COMPUTE E51_HHg = 1 + ((E51_AErw -1) * 0.5) +  (E51_AJugendl * 0.5) + (E51_AKind * 0.3) + (E51_AKleinkind * 0.3).  
EXECUTE. 
RECODE E51_HHg (0.5 = -9) (ELSE = COPY). 
EXECUTE.
```

> ERROR: Variable labels: E51_HHg is not a variable name.

Comment: where is the labels command?

Comment: I did it later. Found the issue though: I put a title above the Command (I used the "*"), and did not leave a blank line in between the title/comment and the command. Thak you for your time and help!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your question for future users who come up with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible reasons:

1. When you `insert` a syntax file you have to make sure the lines are never more than 256 characters. SPSS just won't read characters beyond 256.
2. If your inserted syntax is expecting a different working directory definition than what is defined by the main syntax, it may have trouble finding data files it is supposed to use.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately both are not the case... but i think I forgot to add the execute. function

Comment: no unfortunately. Do you thik I have to remove the user defined missing values when I use the compute function?

Comment: please edit your post and add the insert syntax you are using and a full quote of the error message - maybe that can help understand more